# Determing which variable changes in a difference. i.e. $Y = X_1 - X_2$

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, probability-distributions

I have three independent random variables $X_1$, $X_2$, and $X_3$. Then define $Y_{12} = X_1 - X_2$, $Y_{13} = X_1 - X_3$, $Y_{23} = X_2 - X_3$. In matrix form, we can write $Y = AX$ where

$$ A = \begin{bmatrix}1 & -1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & -1 \\ 0 & 1 & -1\end{bmatrix}.$$

Say we have discrete values for the the $Y$ elements, i.e. $Y_{12}(k) = [Y_{12}(1),Y_{12}(2),\ldots, Y_{12}(n)]$, but we don't have values for the $X$'s.

Now say we can form the distribution for each $Y$ value (i.e. a Gaussian normal distribution). When this distribution changes, is there a way to determine which $X$ value is likely causing the change? For instance, $Y_{12}$ distribution changes based on $X_1$. But we only have discrete values for $Y_{12}$, not $X_1$. Using $Y$, can we determine that it was $X_1$ causing the change?

In terms of linear algebra, I realize that the reduced echelon form of $A$ is $A_\text{red} = \begin{bmatrix}1 & -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & -1\end{bmatrix}$ and its nullspace prevents us from estimating $X_1,X_2,X_3$.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**, it is possible to determine which variable is causing the change in the distribution of Y based on the correlation between the Y values and the individual X values.

To find the correlation between Y and X1, we can calculate the correlation coefficient between Y12 and X1, as Y12 changes based on X1. We can similarly find the correlation coefficients between Y and X2 and X3.

Once we have the correlation coefficients, we can compare them to see which variable has the highest correlation with Y. The variable with the highest correlation coefficient is likely the variable causing the change in the distribution of Y.

Note that this method assumes a linear relationship between the X and Y variables and may not be accurate if there are non-linear relationships or other confounding factors at play.

Comment: How do we compute the correlation between the $Y$ values and the $X$ values if we don't have the $X$ values? The question states that we have discrete values for $Y$, but $X$ is not known. Can we use only $Y$ values to determine which $X$ is changing the distribution?

Comment: @Nick Determining the causal X variable for the change in Y's distribution with only discrete Y values is challenging. Instead, compare Y's distributions across different X levels visually or using measures like mean and variance. If distinct patterns emerge, it suggests an influence from the associated X variable. However, this method has limitations and assumes meaningful Y values influenced solely by X variables.